# How to compare a zero padded number in dictionary with a non zero padded number

Tags: python, python-2.6

I have two files and I need to compare both of them & update the value of the 1st file from the 2nd file.

My first file is as below,

```
SeqNo   City           State
1   Chicago         IL
2   Boston          MA
3   New York    NY
4   Los Angeles CA
5   Seattle         WA
```

My second file is as below,

```
SeqNo   City           State   NewSeqNo
005   Seattle     WA  001
001   Chicago         IL  002
004   Los Angeles CA  003
002   Boston          MA  004
003   New York    NY  005
```

I have the following code to update the SEQ Number in the first file with the value in the NewSeqNo from the second file & save it as a third file. But it throws key error as SEQNO is zero padded in the second file where as its not in the first,

```
import csv

lookup = {}
with open('secondfile') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        oldseq, city, state, newseq = line
        lookup[oldseq] = newseq


with open('firstfile') as f, open('outfile','w') as w:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    for line in reader:
        seq, city, state = line
        if seq in lookup:
            seq = lookup[seq]
        writer.writerow([seq, city, state])
```

For example, the output of the thirs file should be,

```
NewSeqNo   City           State
002   Chicago         IL
004   Boston          MA
005   New York    NY
003   Los Angeles CA
001   Seattle         WA
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What about just convert into int and do equality test `>>> 5 == 005
True
>>>
`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a noob. How do I do that within my script

Comment: Could you possibly format this so that we can read the code? That's particularly important given that Python is whitespace sensitive.

Comment: @user1345260 by using `int()` and the equality op `==`

Answer (score 1):

Convert your 'numbers' to integers to remove the padding before storing in the dictionary:

```
import csv

lookup = {}
with open('secondfile') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for line in reader:
        oldseq, city, state, newseq = line
        lookup[int(oldseq)] = newseq


with open('firstfile') as f, open('outfile','w') as w:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    for line in reader:
        seq, city, state = line
        if int(seq) in lookup:
            seq = lookup[int(seq)]
        writer.writerow([seq, city, state])
```

Now `lookup` has integer keys, and when looking up matching keys in the second loop, we pass in integer keys again.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it is always padded for a length of 3, when reading your first file, you can convert your `seq` to an `int` and use format to write a padded value:

```
with open('firstfile') as f, open('outfile','w') as w:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    writer = csv.writer(w)
    for line in reader:
        seq, city, state = line

        # Convert to padded value
        seq = "{:03}".format(int(seq))

        if seq in lookup:
            seq = lookup[seq]
        writer.writerow([seq, city, state])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

old_dict = dict()
new_dict = dict()
with open('old', 'r') as fh:
    for l in fh.readlines():
        r = l.split()
        if r:
            old_dict.setdefault(int(r[0]), None)
            old_dict[int(r[0])] = ' '.join(r[1:])

with open('new', 'r') as fh:
    for l in fh.readlines():
        r = l.split()
        if r:
            k = ' '.join(r[1:-1])
            new_dict.setdefault(k, None)
            new_dict[k] = int(r[-1])
for i,j in old_dict.iteritems():
    d = j.split()
    print '%0.3d %s %s' % (new_dict[j], ' '.join(d[0:-1]), d[-1])
```

Output:

```
 002 Chicago IL
 004 Boston MA
 005 New York NY
 003 Los Angeles CA
 001 Seattle WA
```